# Simulink signal data type

Tags: types, simulink

I have a simple question. What format are Simulink signals in and specifically what format are they exported in? For example, say I connect a constant of 2 in the format Double to a UDP-Send block. Then at the other end of the network I receive UDP packets with an arbitrary device and program which just lists all data received, what would show up? Would I get the number 2, or would I get the binary equivalent or perhaps the Hex value?

Thanks a lot for your info!

Answer (score 1):

The data you connect to the UDP send block is sent in the **same datatype** as you have specified. If you connect a UDP receive block and connect a scope/display to it, the constant 2 as double will be displayed as 2 itself. Not its binary/hex equivalent.
See this:

[image]

[image]